# How to make R use more CPU in Random Forest

Tags: r, random-forest, cpu-usage, multicore

I have wrote a code that uses `randomForest` function for predicting results for a dataframe with 240 columns and 1700 rows. (It use 240 variables for prediction and there are 1700 records for train).
My problem is that this code runs so slow in a corei7 4600 CPU with 2 cores. (It just use  15% of CPU and less than 600mb of RAM. not even 100% of one core!)

How can I force R (in windows) to use more resources in this process?

Comment: You should think about parallel processing. There are packages for it. Also, not sure if you got the concept of training/testing correctly. You don‘t train and your rows and then predict with your columns. Instead you train on a subset of rows (with all columns) and then test on a hold-out subset of your data (with all columns).

Comment: my training set is 1700 rows and I have other 200 rows for test. I searched about parallel and I used doParallel and doSnow and doMC packages with their main functions but nothing changed!

Comment: Then probably your usage might not have been correct. I remember having used Random Forests with up to 100% CPU usage. WIthout sharing a reproducible example and the code you already tried it's close to impossible to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SinaAlvandi, there are several ways to do parallel programming. When it comes to modelling to use parallelism, the model fitting procedure itself must implement parallelism. For random forest the simplest method is either using the `caret` package as shown [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/random-forest-with-parallel-computing-in-r-programming/) or to use `tidymodels` as shown [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/11/tune-parallel/) or [here](https://tune.tidymodels.org/articles/extras/optimizations.html). Not all algorithms are implemented for parallel processing!